# Laravel Datatable Filters not working

Tags: php, jquery, datatables, laravel-5.3

I am using yajra datatables with my laravel application. My requirement is as explained below,

I have a list of users along with the team they are in. It will load a list with the columns name/email/phone/team/user_status. I have a drop-down with a list of user_status as its values. When I change this drop-down value, on-change event it should automatically filter the list.

Here is my code:
HTML in my view,

```
{!! Form::select('user_status', $status, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
<table id="user-info" class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="padding-top:10px;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th>Team</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JS for datatables,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var oTable = $('#user-info').dataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
      "url":  MY-URL-HERE,
      "type": "GET",
      "error": function(reason) {
         console.log(reason);
      }
    },
    "paging": true,
    "lengthChange": true,
    "searching": false,
    "bInfo": true,
    "bFilter": true,
    "autoWidth": false,
    "dom": '<"top"f>rt<"bottom table-bottom"lpi>',
    "iDisplayLength":15,
    "lengthMenu": [[15, 30, 50, 75, 100, -1], [15, 30, 50, 75, 100, "All"]],
    "bSort": true,
    "ordering": true
  });

  $('#user_status').change( function() {
    oTable.fnFilter( $(this).val(),4);
  });
});
```

My method which return data to datatables,

```
$usersList = AppUser::join('teams as t', 't.id', '=', 'users.team_id')
                      ->where('users.pm_status', '!=', 'active')
                      ->select(DB::raw("CONCAT(users.user_fname,' ',users.user_lname) AS fullname"), 'users.email', 'users.phone', 't.team_name', 'users.user_status')->get();
return Datatables::of($usersList);
```

**My Issue:** It loads the data when the page loads. But the filters seems not working for me when I change the drop-down values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself atlast. Actually it is an issue.
get() is not required in our query when using datatables.
So, the query in my controller should look like below,

```
$usersList = AppUser::join('teams as t', 't.id', '=', 'users.team_id')
                  ->where('users.pm_status', '!=', 'active')
                  ->select(DB::raw("CONCAT(users.user_fname,' ',users.user_lname) AS fullname"), 'users.email', 'users.phone', 't.team_name', 'users.user_status');
return Datatables::of($usersList);
```